# Getting error Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/app/.next/BUILD_ID'

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, next.js

I'm trying to Dockerize a basic NextJS setup with nginx based on [this](https://steveholgado.com/nginx-for-nextjs/) tutorial.

I have a NextJS app written in typescript and with a custom Express server, which I deploy to Heroku. It builds and the server file at `.next/production-server/server.js` gets served.

When I try to Dockerize the app as in the above guide, I run in the error,

```
Getting error Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/app/.next/BUILD_ID'
```

I've tried running `chmod` to grant access to the `node` user from node alpine, but it keeps throwing the same error.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I were to clone the repo from [here](https://github.com/steveholgado/nextjs-docker-pm2-nginx), directly from that guide, and run `docker-compose up`, then it seems to work fine. But it seems that the moment I try to add TS configuration to it, it fails.

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN npm install --global pm2

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install --production

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm run build

USER node # <----------------- seems to fail with this user

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

My Github repo is [here](https://github.com/mkhoussid/nextjs-ts-docker).

If comment out the line `USER node`, then it works fine.

Comment: i am having a similar problem but mine is caused by volumes

Comment: I also have this problem

Comment: I have same issue